# Why os Fedora is calling containers on startup?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, docker

My fedora distro is messed up with docker containers...

Everytime I restart this I need to call "docker ps" and then call "docker kill" for each container that is running...

How can I discover who is calling this containers or prevent they to be called on startup?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple causes for this.  Try running "docker inspect ContainerName" and taking a look at the restart policy.  If enabled, it could cause the container to start at boot.

Also, external functions like upstart, systemd, and supervisord could be starting the containers (often used when non-container functions rely on the existence of a container before starting).  For my own rig, I'm using monit to start/restart containers (I like that you can define the number of restart attempts before giving up).